# Flavour enhancers

Tags: food-science, chemistry, flavor

I've read that vanilla is usually used to highlight/enhance the flavour of chocolate, lemon juice the flavour of strawberries, and MSGs the flavour of meat. What other flavour enhancers are out there? 
Asides salt and sugar..

Comment: I thought coffee was used to enhance chocolate.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, fat and acid are. If you already consider salt,sugar,glutamates - anything that influences TASTE directly but not flavour/aroma and is not bitter (given recent research, we can taste more than one kind of bitter, which fits in there interestingly...)

Glutamic acid in other forms than its sodium salt (to be found in a lot of ingredients).

In industrially made products, inosinate and guanylate compounds are frequently used. For example, japanese kare roux cubes, and golden mountain soy sauce contain them. Such compounds are frequently non vegetarian unless stated.

Recently, some substances have been isolated and marketed that purport to enhance the newly found "kokumi" sensation.

There are certain chemicals marketed that REDUCE the sensation of sweetness or saltiness, or bind rancid-tasting molecules into an inert form (pea dextrin).

Comment: Some googling also suggest pyridine compounds (maillard reaction products, synthetically made), but these might be better classified as flavours. And 5-acetoxymethyl-2-furaldehyde seems to be a recent addition for sweet things...